Phrase or expression for being on the second level in terms of worseness

Emigration rate for this country is only lower than that of war-zone
countries.

The sentence is meant to say that the emigration rate of this country is so high that is right after that of war-zone countries.
Is there any phrase or expression for the “is only lower than” in the above sentence?

"Is second only to". But this idiom is rather used with positive connotations. Like second best, I guess.

@fev Yes, my context is negative.

You could say something like "is only exceeded by". As mentioned, idioms for "second best" are far more common.

Do you mean emigration? A war-zone country doesn't have people wanting to get in; it has people wanting to get out.

You shouldn't fix the vocabulary “error” when it's been pointed out in an answer. Personally, immigration works just as well: a country with a high number of immigrants.  Dictionary def: the action of coming to live permanently in a foreign country.

Emigration is not the proper word to use for the act of people fleeing a war zone.

What is “in terms of ⁇worseness” intended to mean? Deriving a noun by aﬀixing the normally highly productive ‑ness suﬀix to an adjective or adverb that’s already been inflected into its comparative or superlative degrees instead of to the base form is at best suspect—if not outright unacceptable—to most native speakers. For whatever the reason, we don’t much like such attempts as ❌olderness, ❌youngestness, ❌bestness, ❌biggestness, ❌furtherness, ❌littlerness, ❌lesserness, ❌leastness, ❌tinierness, ❌unfriendliestness, etc. You should probably say “in terms of how bad it is” instead.

I think you mean to say emigration not immigration.
The construction you want is to be second only to {something}.

The emigration rate of this country is second only to that of war-zone countries.
This country is second only to war-zone countries in rate of emigration.
In its rate of emigration this country is second only to war-zone countries.

It means that only war-zone countries have a rate of people wanting to leave  that is higher than this country's rate of people wanting to leave.
“Second only to.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/second%20only%20to. Accessed 30 May. 2024.
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/second-only-to-something

Either it's emigration or immigration, in which case it should be higher than instead of lower than.

@user405662 What is the referent of "in which case" in your comment?

Only war-zone countries have lower immigration rates.  But it's odd to compare a country's immigration rate to that of countries people are fleeing.

One could say "This country has the lowest immigration rate in the world, apart from countries in active war-zones."

It might not be literally ‘second’. Actually, on the top are the most populous countries, then war-zone counties, and then the country in question. Does ‘only second to’ works here too?

The object of the preposition "to" in "second only to {grammatical object} in {something}" can be a group considered as one, e.g.  "We are second only to the major industrialized nations in {something}".  But "the most populous countries" is rather vague. Where is the cutoff point?

"A is second only to X in terms of Y" means that only X has more Y than A does".  Y can be something good or bad.  Nobel laureates or homicides.

@Sasan It works because we're considering the war-torn countries as a group with similar rates.

Consider “almost as bad as” as a possibility. “Next worse to” is poot writing even if it works in some math contexts.

It would be interesting to know why you think that "next worse to" is poor writing.

I didn't downvote; I asked why because I didn't have an obvious explanation of the logic of this expression, but that is all. // Your solution is an option.

"Next worse" is one possibility.
( The skeleton in the cupboard - lady Harriet Anne Scott · 1861) She could not bear reading or writing, and reading a letter was next worse to writing one.
(Prospect Theory: For Risk and Ambiguity - Peter P. Wakker · 2010) For each outcome    α, calculate the marginal w contribution of its outcome probability p to its rank; i.e., calculate w(p+r) - w(r). Note that w(p + r) is the rank of the outcome in the prospect next-worse to α.

Immigration rate for this country is next worse to that of war-zone countries.


This expression was used more frequently in the 19th century and in the first twenty years of the 20th, but it seems to be still in use.

I have doubts about “next worse to.”. But I don”t think war zones are great attractors of immigrants.

@Xanne What do you mean? Does ‘immigration rate’ of a country mean how many people immigrate to that country?

Logically, it is rather "emigration". e-, ex- (out), im- in- (in). It could be understood, though, that the countries are those in the vicinity of a country at war; they are often those where migrants seek a refuge.

People flee war zones, usually; citizens abroad  may return to fight or otherwise help.   So  statements need to be carefully written.

Usually a net immigration or emigration number becomes available. Very hard ro estimate for war zones.

I'm not a native English speaker but 'next worse to' sounds weird to me too. I've never heard any fluent speaker say something like this. You've quoted a mathematical article wherein the usage next-worse sounds like a jargon-ish phrase, and an article from over a century ago. Perhaps it's an old-fashioned way of phrasing?

Also, the author of the math article is Dutch, perhaps that makes a difference as well

@paddotk The fact that it is in a foreign writer's text could be a proof of the currency in the language:  this expression was not invented by people from non-English speaking countries, and you must have read it a great enough number of times before you feel confortable with it. In fact it is found quite a bit in religious text  in the 19th century, which shows that it was used by well-educated people.  Here is another recent example: https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Rosemary_and_Rue_by_Amber/GvzXDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22next+worse+to%22&pg=PT101&printsec=frontcover

My assumption: "this country" refers to an unspecified country that is currently not involved in military conflict or is under siege.

Emigration rate for this country is just below that of war-zone countries.

Invented statistics
Percentage of emigrants from war-torn and/or war zone countries: 18%
Percentage of emigrants from "this country": 17%
If the difference is greater than 3%, remove “just” or use @TimR's solution, second only to.

...is exceeded only by...
"The emigration rate for this country is exceeded only by war-zone countries."
i.e. war-zones are the only countries with a rate higher than this country.
